# Populate a variable from print output in a loop

Tags: python

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=
    [['22 take away', 'something'],
     ['takeaway 56', 'I see'],
     ['45 takeaway street', ' This is blue'],
     ['right street', ' This is white']],
    columns=['V1', 'V2']
)
```

I want to extract the numbers from V1 to a separate variable in that dataframe using regex pattern. I have the following till now:

```
pattern =  r'\d{1,2}'
for i in df.V1:
    num = re.search(pattern, i)
    if num:
        print(num.group(0))
```

This prints out the numbers but my tries to separate these in a variable are all wrong till now. My goal is to have the following dataframe:

```
dfgoal = pd.DataFrame(
    data=
    [['22 take away', 'something', '22'],
     ['takeaway 56', 'I see', '56'],
     ['45 takeaway street', ' This is blue', '45'],
    ['right street', ' This is white', ' ']],
    columns=['V1', 'V2', 'V3']
)
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Use `df.V1.str.extract()`

Comment: Why would you expect it to save those matches to a new column when you never ask it to? All you do is `print` the match.

Comment: It's _possible_ to redirect your prints to a StringIO object or similar, but by far the better solution is _not to do this at all_ and replace `print` with a `yield` or `someList.append()` or similar. Is some external requirement forcing you to use `print` here?

Comment: Thanks. I know this was only printing the numbers - this was merely my try to start working to have the 3rd variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `print` but `append` value to some `list` and later assign this `list` to `df["V3"]`

And remeber to add empty string when it doesn't find `num`

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['22 take away', 'something'],
        ['takeaway 56', 'I see'],
        ['45 takeaway street', ' This is blue'],
        ['right street', ' This is white']
    ],
    columns=['V1', 'V2']
)

# ------------

results = []

pattern =  r'\d{1,2}'

for i in df.V1:
    num = re.search(pattern, i)
    if num:
        #print(num.group(0))
        results.append(num.group(0))
    else:
        results.append("")
        
df['V3'] = results

# ------------

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                   V1              V2  V3
0        22 take away       something  22
1         takeaway 56           I see  56
2  45 takeaway street    This is blue  45
3        right street   This is white
```

---

**EDIT:**

It is simpler to use [.str.extract(pattern)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) (as  @Barmar suggested in comment).

But pattern needs `( )` to capture value.

When it doesn't find number then it puts `NaN` and it needs `.fillna("")` to replace `NaN` with empty string.

```
pattern =  r'(\d{1,2})'
        
df['V3'] = df['V1'].str.extract(pattern).fillna("")
```